# Hierarchical query on a temporary table works but is not ordering results as it should

Tags: sql, oracle

i have a hierarchical query :

```
with temp1 as (
select distinct 
    b.ID,
    b.LABEL,
    b.parent_id
from my_table b
where b.PROG_MODIF_ID=:P225_PROG_MODIF
)
,temp2 as (
select distinct 
    b.ID,
    b.LABEL,
    p.id as p_id,
    b.parent_id
from temp1 b
left join temp1 p on p.id=b.parent_id
)
select distinct 
    b.ID,
    b.p_id,
    b.LABEL,
    b.parent_id
from temp2 b

start with b.p_id is null
connect by
prior b.id=b.p_id
```

the results i get with this query are correct but they are not ordered as need be : meaning every parents with its children below, instead they r ordered randomly even though the "parent-child" link is specified `b.id=b.p_id`

EDIT : the query at first had  `order siblings by b.id` , but it wasn't working instead it was ordering the parents and siblings all the same and the result was parents in the middle of or below their children.
EDIT 2 : i found that the problem was a CASE i was using in the query, somehow for some reason, when i add that CASE column the order goes nuts and when i remove it it works just fine...

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` statement for your table; the `INSERT` statements for your sample data; an English description (not code) of what you are trying to achieve; and the expected output for your sample data. Trying to reverse engineer the problem from a sample of code that you tell us is not correct (but don't tell us what would be correct) is a very difficult task.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to simplify it to a single hierarchical query using an `ORDER SIBLINGS BY` clause:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
       id,
       label,
       PRIOR id AS p_id,
       parent_id
FROM   my_table
START WITH
       parent_id IS NULL
AND    prog_modif_id = :P225_PROG_MODIF
CONNECT BY
       PRIOR id = parent_id
AND    prog_modif_id = :P225_PROG_MODIF
ORDER SIBLINGS BY
       label
```

However, without a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to test.

Comment: i added an edit explaining how ORDER SIBLINGS BY didn't work for me, and for the PARENT_ID IS NULL i needed the temp table to make the parent's parent NULL because it is not originally NULL (the hierarchy goes way up and i only need the leafs and occasionally their parents)

Answer (score 0):

The resultset from a query has no intrinsic order. If you want to order the records then you need to include an ORDER BY clause

Answer (score 0):

i found that adding a CASE column was the problem in my query so i commented itm hte query after @MT0 's suggestion looks like this:

```
select distinct 
    b.ID,
    b.LABEL,
    b.parent_id
    --case when (select count(*) from budget_equip p where p.parent_id=b.id and p.PROG_MODIF_ID=:P225_PROG_MODIF)>0 then 'underline' else 'none' end as text_decoration
from my_table b
where b.PROG_MODIF_ID=:P225_PROG_MODIF

START WITH --p.id IS NULL
(select count(*) from budget_equip p where p.parent_id=b.id and p.PROG_MODIF_ID=:P225_PROG_MODIF)>0
CONNECT BY
       PRIOR id = parent_id
ORDER SIBLINGS BY label
```

still can't figure a way around the CASE .